# Floating Action bar menu appears across every fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I am using an library called CircularFloating to show menu in my homepage in one fragment but when i click and go to the next fragmetn it still appears to be in next fragment also. how can I remove or set visibility off when I move to next fragments.

here is my code.

```html
        SubActionButton.Builder itemBuilder = new SubActionButton.Builder(getActivity());
        ImageView itemIcon1 = new ImageView(getActivity());
        itemIcon1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.camera_button));
        SubActionButton button1 = itemBuilder.setContentView(itemIcon1).build();

        ImageView itemIcon2 = new ImageView(getActivity());
        itemIcon2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_action_dark_touch));
        SubActionButton button2 = itemBuilder.setContentView(itemIcon2).build();


       final  FloatingActionMenu actionMenu = new FloatingActionMenu.Builder(getActivity())
                .addSubActionView(button1)
                .addSubActionView(button2)
                .attachTo(actionButton)
                .build();




        itemIcon2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                Fragment abt = new Feedback_Fragment();
                ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, abt).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                actionMenu.close(true);


            }
        });
```

Library I have used is

```html
implementation 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the visibility with

```
actionMenu.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```

or

```
actionMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

And set the visibility to `visible` again with

```
actionMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly how this library is built, you could try playing around with the attribute
`app:elevation="0"`. Try to set this attribute to the layout that is currently appearing on top of all fragments, if this attribute is available for that layout. If not, try setting it for the `FloatingActionButtons`. Hope this helps.